# Configure spring cloud contract and Zuul proxy in the same project

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-feign

I have a problem with integrating spring-cloud-contract with my service on the consumer side. In my service I use already feign (to call other services) and zuul (for routing) from spring-cloud. The problem happens when I try to run a test annotated with @AutoConfigureStubRunner. This my simple class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"group:artifact:+:stubs:8080"}, workOffline = true)
public class WithContractTests {
    @Test
    public void test() {}
}
```

In the output I can see that stubs were started properly:

```
o.s.c.c.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor    : All stubs are now running RunningStubs [namesAndPorts={group:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:stubs=8080}]
```

And then I have this error while creating spring context:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.cloud.StubRunnerDiscoveryClient.getServices(StubRunnerDiscoveryClient.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.0.0.RC1.jar:1.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.locateRoutes(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.locateRoutes(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator.doRefresh(SimpleRouteLocator.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.refresh(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping.setDirty(ZuulHandlerMapping.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration$ZuulRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(ZuulConfiguration.java:180) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:79) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getOptional(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.feign(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:157) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RC1.jar:1.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

What is interesting is that the same error occurs in the spring-cloud-contract example:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/samples/standalone/dsl/http-client after adding Zuul to the project. By adding Zuul I mean adding **spring-cloud-starter-zuul** as dependency and **@EnableZuulProxy** annotation. After that we can see a following error while executing the test:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.cloud.StubRunnerDiscoveryClient.getServices(StubRunnerDiscoveryClient.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-1.0.0.BUILD-20160922.090756-647.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.locateRoutes(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.locateRoutes(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator.doRefresh(SimpleRouteLocator.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.refresh(DiscoveryClientRouteLocator.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping.setDirty(ZuulHandlerMapping.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration$ZuulRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(ZuulConfiguration.java:180) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.BUILD-20160922.110240-890.jar:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160728.175440-591.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160728.175440-591.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-20160728.175440-591.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111) [spring-boot-test-1.4.0.BUILD-20160728.175440-528.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
```

Do I need some additional configuration when using Zuul together with Stub runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy this is my mistake. Can you file an issue in contract? Until now you would have to do is to override the existing class woth sth that doesn't add servers to a list returned from a delegate but creates a new list to which the servers are added. I haven't tested that against Zuul :/

It's been fixed (hopefully) here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/82

Comment: Ok, thanks for information, I created a ticket for spring-cloud-contract

Comment: The issue was fixed indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's awesome! Can you mark this issue as answered?